# how do I further the lines below in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,angles,quotes,external}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   scale = 1,
   angle radius = 7mm,
my angle/.style = {draw,
                   angle eccentricity=1.2,
                   font=\footnotesize,
                   <->}, % angle label position!
    Arrow/.style= {ultra thick,red,-stealth,
                   shorten <=7mm, %shorten >=0.5mm,
                   draw=gray}
                    ]
\coordinate  (c) at (0,0);
\draw[thick] (c) circle(1.3cm);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {30,45}
{
% dots at each point
    \filldraw[gray] (\x:1.3cm) circle(1pt);
% lines from center to point
    \draw[black,->] (c) -- coordinate (m\i) (\x:1.3cm) coordinate (a\i);
}
%\pic [my angle,"$x$"]  {angle = a1--c--a2};
% left image, simulated by node
\node (li)  [draw, minimum size=20mm,align=center,left]  at (-2,0) {aaaaaa};
\node (ri)  [draw, minimum size=20mm,align=left,right] at ( 2,0) {bbbbb};
    \draw[Arrow]    (li.east) to [out=45, in=135]  (m2);
    \draw[Arrow]    (ri.west) to [out=225,in=-60]  (m1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The gray lines that connect the circle to the boxes on the left and on the right do not actually touch the edge of the box (as I thought li.easy and ri.west would do). What is the way to fix that?

Comment: The issue comes from `shorten <=7mm` in your definition of the `Arrow` style.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove `shorten <=7mm` from the definition of the `Arrow` style or use

```
\draw[Arrow, shorten <=0mm]    (li.east) to [out=45, in=135]  (m2);
\draw[Arrow, shorten <=0mm]    (ri.west) to [out=225,in=-60]  (m1);
```

for the arrows.